# .click() Javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been programming a website recently. However, when I add this function:

```
var getInput = function() {
    $('#inputSubmit').click(function() {
        return $('input[name=input1]').val();
)};  
};
```

My text code breaks. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: syntax error in the 2nd last line. should be `});`

Comment: Please do proper research before asking questions 

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var getInput = function() {
    $('#inputSubmit').click(function() {
        return $('input[name="input1"]').val(); // added " "
});  // )} --> })
};
```